# GraphQL Mutation not working with RuntimeWiring.newRuntimeWiring()

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

I have defined a simple schema in GraphQL Java to add `Book` and to fetch the `[Book]`. My Schema goes like:

```
schema {
 query: Query
 mutation : Mutation
}

type Query {
 allBooks: [Book]
 book(id: String): Book
}

type Book {
  isn: String
  title: String
  publisher: String
  author: String
  publishedDate: String
}

input BookType {
  isn: String
  title: String
  publisher: String
  author: String
  publishedDate: String
}

type Mutation {
  newBook(
      isn: String!,
      title: String!,
      publisher: String!,
      authors:String!,
      publishedDate: String!
  ): Book
}
```

I have create the runtime wiring like this:

```
RuntimeWiring.newRuntimeWiring()
  .type("Query", typeWiring ->
    typeWiring.dataFetcher("allBooks", allBooksDataFetcher))
  .type("Mutation", typeWiring ->
    typeWiring.dataFetcher("newBook", addBooksDataFetcher))
  .build();
```

The `allBooks` query is working fine but the `newBook` mutation is not working and gives following error:

```
"errors": [
  {
    "validationErrorType": "FieldUndefined",
    "message": "Validation error of type FieldUndefined: Field oneBook is undefined",
    "locations": [
      {
        "line": 3,
        "column": 3
      }
    ],
    "errorType": "ValidationError"
  }
],
  "data": null,
  "extensions": null
}
```

The mutation through Postman is:

```
{
  newBook(
    isn:"1",
    title: "test title",
    publisher: "test publisher",
    authors:"test author",
    publishedDate: "2 Nov 2018"
  ) {
    title
  }
}
```

Please help me out. Its not picking up the Mutation Type but Query is working absolutely fine. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the error is referring to, but you do need to include the operation (`query` vs `mutation`) when performing a mutation. That is, your request should look more like this:

```
mutation ArbitraryOperationName {
  newBook(
    isn:"1",
    title: "test title",
    publisher: "test publisher",
    authors:"test author",
    publishedDate: "2 Nov 2018"
  ) {
    title
  }
}
```

When writing queries, you can use the shorthand notation and omit the `query` keyword, but mutations must always include `mutation` to indicate that you are making a mutation and not a query.

Comment: Thanks Daniel , it worked :) i was missing to include mutation keyword . Thank you very much :)